# How to get user`s files from 'Files' tab using system admin token (REST API)?

Tags: rest, api, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

As a system administrator, I want to fetch all the files uploaded by a specific user. I found out that using the request to `GET /services/data/v48.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+ContentDocument+USING+SCOPE+Everything` I can fetch all the files from my organization uploaded by different users.

Can I do the same for a specific user?
If yes, then how?

Does this require the user`s access token to fetch files and also upload them? Or can it be done using only system admin token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you need `SCOPE`. System Administrator will have "View All Data, Query All Files", should be enough according to the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm). Check the profile/permission sets, experiment a bit.

This should be a good start:

```
SELECT Id, OwnerId, CreatedById, Title
FROM ContentDocument
WHERE CreatedById = '005...' OR OwnerId = '005...'
```

You'll need to know the user's `Id` or you can do JOINs (called [relationship queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_lookup.htm) in SF) `WHERE CreatedBy.Username = 'x@y.com'`